# Erro ao somar usando join e sub-query - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query

Boa tarde,

Tenho duas tabelas que preciso realizar a soma porém ele está agrupando.

*Correçao:

A regra do negócio é que existem notas , em que o usuario pode fazer varios depositos em cima dos id das notas. O problema é que ao fazer a soma de cada deposito que foi feito em id_nota , ele acaba agrupando.

A tabela 1 com *NOTAS* está assim:

```
            id_nota  | 

            ----------
            1        |
            2        |
            3        |
            4        |
```

A tabela 2 de nome *DEPOSITO* está assim:

```
        id_deposito  |   id_nota |  valor_deposito |
        ---------------------------------------------
        1            |     1     |  200.00
        2            |     1     |  250.00
        3            |     3     |  300.00
        4            |     3     |  350.00
        5            |     4     |  400.00
```

Ao fazer o join com essas duas tabela ele me retorna cada linha com a soma de todas e nao a soma de cada por id.

```
select *
from deposito 
cross join (SELECT SUM(valor_deposito) as amount FROM deposito AS amount) b
inner join notas on notas.id_nota = deposito.id_nota
```

Ele me retorna assim :

```
        id_deposito  |   id_nota |  valor_deposito | amount
        ---------------------------------------------
        1            |     1     |  200.00         | 1500.00
        2            |     1     |  250.00         | 1500.00
        3            |     3     |  300.00         | 1500.00
        4            |     3     |  350.00         | 1500.00
        5            |     4     |  400.00         | 1500.00
```

Ele deveria me retornar assim:

```
        id_deposito  |   id_nota |  valor_deposito | amount
        ---------------------------------------------
        1            |     1     |  200.00         | 450.00
        2            |     1     |  250.00         | 450.00
        3            |     3     |  300.00         | 650.00
        4            |     3     |  350.00         | 650.00
        5            |     4     |  400.00         | 400.00
```

Comment: Sem uma explicação da sua regra de negócio e do que os dados significam fica bem difícil dar uma resposta. Seu join me parece errado, quando você utiliza o CROSS não há vínculo, fora que me parece estranho utilizar um `SUM` dentro disso.

Comment: Creio que seu subselect deveria conter a cláusula GROUP BY id_nota e deveria ser um INNER JOIN USING id_nota, se bem que não entendi o propósito de sua query.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT SUM(deposito2.valor_deposito) FROM deposito deposito2 WHERE deposito2.id_nota = deposito.id_nota ) AS amount
from deposito 
inner join notas on notas.id_nota = deposito.id_nota
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz um teste assim:

```
SELECT SUM(valor_deposito) FROM deposito INNER JOIN notas IN deposito.id_nota = notas.id GROUP BY notas.id;
```